# How do you move from Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu Gnome 14.10?

Tags: gnome, 14.10, repository

I am currently using Ubuntu but installed the PPA for Gnome 3.12 and am using this instead of Unity. I'd actually like to just use Ubuntu Gnome. How do I set up my system to remove the LDM and just use GDM? Is it just a matter of uninstalling packages or do I need to change over to an Ubuntu Gnome repository?

Comment: I made the change a while back, but at that time I re-installed from scratch using the Ubuntu-Gnome distribution.

Comment: You could've just done `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I did end up removing/purging the PPA and then reinstalling the GNOME packages from the repository. I then removed Unity. Let's hope my system stays stable.